# how make a search engine in device

Tags: ruby-on-rails

someone could help me to implement a search in my index file on the device framework, and I managed to do it in Active Admin, but I need to implement it in my views. I implemented ruby on rails 3.2.13.
The code I have is:

```
<h1>Lista de alumnos</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th> Nombre </th>
    <th> Apellido </th>
    <th> CURP </th>
    <th> Genero </th>
  </tr>
<% @alumnos.each do |alumno| %>

  <tr>
    <th><%= alumno.nombre %></th> 
    <th><%= alumno.apellido %></th>
    <th><%= alumno.curp %></th>
    <th><%= alumno.genero %></th>

    <td><%= link_to 'Muestra', alumno %>|</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_alumno_path(alumno) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Eliminar', alumno, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'Nuevo Alumno', new_alumno_path %>
```

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on what you mean by the `Device` framework a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You question is very shallow but I'm going to answer it anyway. I'm going to show you how to implement simple search.
First step. Add this to the model you want to implement search on i.e in your case it might be alumnos.rb

```
def self.search(query)
    if query
      where("FIELD_TO_SEARCH like ?", "%#{query}%") 
    else
      scoped
    end
end
```

NB: Replace `FIELD_TO_SEARCH` with the particular field that you want to be searched from the alumnos model. An example in your case could be nombre. Next you've got to change your @alumnos variable in index method in your controller to the following

```
def index
  @alumnos = Model_Name.search(params[:search])
end
```

Remember to change Model_Name with the name of your model. Finally your views would look like

```
<%= form_tag(alumis_path, :method => 'get', id: "search-form") do %>
    <div class="search"><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Search' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps you in understanding how you can implement simple search on 'Devise' as you say which you didn't elaborate as expected.